# How do I get the value of a key if it contains a "/" in Rest Assured / java?

Tags: rest, rest-assured

```
Example json is
{
"model": {
"sub-model": {
"/example/1":"alaska",
"value": "Consistently"
}
}
}
```

I tried to fetch the value of the key -"/example/1" with the below code and I am getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The parameter "1" was used but not defined. Define parameters using the JsonPath.params(...) function

```
String keyVal=given()
                .when()
                .get(url)
                .then().extract().path("model.sub-model./example/1");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you just have to put your `/example/1` in `"` like this:

```
String keyVal=given()
                .when()
                .get(url)
                .then().extract().path("model.sub-model.\"/example/1\"");
```

I also added backslash as it's special escape character in Java. Adding the `"` alone would cause termination of the `String`.

Comment: Thanks, Fenio for your reply. I applied the above fix but It  did not work as I am getting null value for the key

Comment: @UdhayGajula Make sure your json path is correct. In the code you used `cache` element but it does not exist in provided JSON

Comment: Good spot on, Fenio. My bad, I added cache in the key by mistake. But still result is the same what I mean is I am getting null value for the above key

Comment: Here is my updated code:String keyVal=given()
                .when()
                .get(url)
                .then().extract().path("model.sub-model.\"/example/1\"");

Comment: @UdhayGajula I don't know why you get `null`. Try to print the response in the console to verify if you got correct json

Comment: Unfortunately I could not post the json here as it is my project related and it is confidential. For people understanding I have mimic the json same as What I have in my project. As a solution, I have applied the same fix that was mentioned above and I could see the right json printed in the console. The reason being getting null for the key is as it is not finding the \"/example/1\" in json and hence it is showing the value as null for the key. Do you have any working example for the solution that you mentioned above? If you have that would be really great help

Comment: I tested the solution before I posted the answer and I got correct results

Comment: I can't thank you enough, Fenio. I got the proper results this time instead of null.

Comment: @UdhayGajula You can thank me by accepting my answer :)

Comment: I tried this way also on top of your suggestion, Fenio and it worked for me

String keyVal=given()
                .when()
                .get(url)
                .then().extract().path("model.'sub-model'.'/example/1'");

Comment: @UdhayGajula I'm glad you managed to get it to work :) Happy coding!